# Can any one please provide Curl Command to get Artifact from Nexus in Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, curl, jenkins-groovy

Please provide Curl command to download the artifact from nexus with username and password.

Comment: It would be a shell step with the same syntax as if from your cmd line. But there are better options, like let maven do it!

Answer (score 0):

[The Assets API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/integrations/rest-and-integration-api/assets-api) mentions how to get the download URL for some asset, and it uses username and password with curl:

```
curl -u admin:admin123 -X GET 'http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/assets?repository=maven-central'
```

Once you have that, run curl again with the download URL you obtained:

```
curl -u admin:admin123 -X GET 'http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-central/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1-sources.jar'
```